# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I don't know I get the error. 
I already display the params using

`logger.info the params['barangay']['id']
 "barangay" => {"id" => "3"}`

Also I already searched the same error but I guessed I didn't figured it out.

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default',:name => nil %>
    <%= collection_select(:barangay, :id, Barangay.order(:barangay), :id, :barangay, prompt: 'Choose Barangay') %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>



def index
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  logger.info "#{params[:barangay][:id]}"

end
```

Comment: Probably `params[:barangay]` is giving `nil`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit when I tried to display in the console I got {"id" => "3"} .. does it mean it is blank params?

Comment: try logger.info "#{params["barangay"]["id"]}"

Comment: @ShifaKhan Didn't work sir, I got the same error.

Comment: Do logger.info params.inspect. Paste the full results

Comment: @RichardAE '{"utf8"=>"✓", "barangay"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "search"=>"", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"users"}' ... that was the result.

Comment: from which line are you getting the error?

Comment: The line where I put the logger.info "#{params[:barangay][:id]}"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like syntax error. You should use:
`logger.info "#{params[:barangay]['id']}"`
instead of symbolic
`logger.info "#{params[:barangay][:id]}"` in index method.

Comment: It was just a typo error sir. I tried again the logger.info "#{params[:barangay][:id]}" It got the same error.